# Allow to input only a specific mobile phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it's possible to input only a specific mobile phone number for example starting with 0917 and 0916 and so on. Plus the +63917 or the +6316 only and so on with their number.

I've been thinking of doing it using jquery masked input. But I dont know how to make, maybe a variable or sets of array that only will allow the first prefixes of numbers.

or I could also use a javascript if possible?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221866/regex-for-phone-number-in-javascript, basic solution is regex.

Comment: You didn't even try searching before asking did you?

Comment: @degenerate . I'm searching by jquery and javascript. but by regexp? no.

Comment: Regular expressions are very powerful. If you ever need any string searching or manipulation done, "he's your guy". Cheers