# Phone/Fax regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a beginner in regex.

I need a regular expression which satisfies following criteria. I tried lot of things but couldn't make it.

1. total no. of digits can be 10, 11 or 12
2. expression can except characters like `-`, `(`, `)`, space, `/`, `\`
3. expression can start with any digit/character mentioned above
4. max length of the expression is 16.
5. All digits and characters can appear in random order in expression

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221866/regex-for-phone-number-in-javascript

Comment: Even if you didn't succeed, it is worthwhile to show what you attempted. Not only does it confirm you've made an effort, but it's a good starting point for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this pattern seems to work as requested `^(?=(?:\D*\d){10,12}\D*$)[0-9 \-()\\\/]{1,16}$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yX4zR5)

Answer (score 0):

The expression `[ 0-9()\-/\\]{10,16}` fulfills all your requirements.

`[...]` is a positive character class definition. A matching character can be one of the characters in the square brackets.

The first character in the square brackets is a space character.

`0-9` defines all digits (from charcter 0 to character 9). `\d` could be also used for any digit.

`(` and `)` are also valid characters.

The character `-` has a special meaning in square brackets as you can see on `0-9` and therefore must be escaped in square brackets by the backslash character when it should be interpreted as literal character.

The slash is the next character. Please note that also the slash must be escaped with a backslash when using this regular expression in a JavaScript RegExp object.

And the last character with the square brackets is the backslash character which must be always escaped with one more backslash as it is the escape character if the backslash should be interpreted as literal character.

`{10,16}` ... means that the preceding expression must be positively applied on a string for at least 10 but not more than 16 characters.

But you should really search for expressions matching phone numbers in WWW as this is a very often needed expression. You should not reinvent the wheel respectively the expression.

Comment: your pattern does not limit the number of digits to be 10,11 or 12 per the first criteria!

Comment: That's right. But I did not want to make the regular expression for the beginner more complex than necessary by making the expression more restrictive than perhaps really necessary for the input data. The questioner has not written for which purpose the expression is needed: find or validate phone/fax numbers. However, you have posted already a more complex expression for validation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using http://regexlib.com for your RegEx needs. Very good site with tons of RegEx's that you can browse on. I also recommend http://regex101.com for testing regular expressions. Has a very great tool to help you build/modify/test your expressions.